# Make a broken Flag

Tags: modeling

I want to make a flag with holes and a bit rundown, like this:[image]

I have this rn:
[image]

Should i use a Opacity Mask, or use some modelling technique.
Or something else

Comment: use an alpha mask on your image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the alpha channel to create transparency:

[image]

Or simply cut the mesh with the knife:

[image]

France after Waterloo:

[image]

Comment: LOL ....France after Waterloo....love it!!!! +1

Comment: i will not make a rotten German flag for WWI and WWII :D

Comment: @Chris ah ah that's what I thought

Comment: I think cutting the mesh is better, since it will not be simulating the (now nonexistent) cloth connections in the tears

Comment: sure, you can also mix both the 2 methods actually